# For what size of projects we should use play framework and when to use Spring?

Tags: spring, playframework, playframework-2.0

Already Spring framework is used in most of the online web application development then why do we need the Play framework ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using both Spring and Play Framework. I think both have pros and contras. Spring is more like the industry standard for enterprise web applications in Java - Play is younger and had the chance to learn from prior frameworks.

First I'd say to develop web applications with Play is much faster - you press refresh in your browser and you can see the changes you've just done. In Spring you have to compile the project, put it into your container and restart your container (at my work this can take several minutes (which is also nice because one can check for the latest news or emails)).

An advantage of Play is that it's easier to learn, it doesn't have such a huge API as Spring. On the other side this is Spring's strong side: It just has more possibilities. For every problem you most likely find some kind of solution in Spring. In Play you sometimes are kind of lost, what brings us to the documentation of both Frameworks. For Spring one can find an abundance of docs and tutorials online. For Play we have the excellent documentation of Play itself but apart from that it's scarce. Also: If you asking a question regarding Spring on Stackoverflow, you'll get several answers quite fast - if you ask something about Play you sometimes get no answer at all. Spring's community is just bigger than Play's one.

Another point that's annoying in Spring is configuration. Spring configuration can be done in XML, Java annotations or in a configuration class. What sound versatile in the beginning, can become a mess, where it's difficult to understand where one property or bean is defined - they sometimes just appear like magic. In Play you mostly have one location to configure something.

Put it all together, I'd recommend Play for smaller projects, prototypes or (micro-) services. Spring on the other side I'd use for bigger projects.

Edit: It's also possible to use Play together with Spring, e.g. with [Spring's dependency injection](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-java-spring) (although Play now uses Guice as default) or [Spring JPA](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-spring-data-jpa).

Comment: Good Play-questions on SO usually get answered rather quickly, but you are right. the Spring-community is bigger. I'd recommend Play for rapid development and not just for prototyping.